# Lost Connection in query

Tags: php, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM user_info LEFT JOiN general_information ON user_info.username = general_information.vendor_id LEFT JOIN company_information ON user_info.username = company_information.vendor_id LEFT JOIN usa_on_shore_site_locations ON user_info.username = usa_on_shore_site_locations.vendor_id LEFT JOIN core_competencies ON user_info.username = core_competencies.vendor_id LEFT JOIN industries_served ON user_info.username = industries_served.vendor_id LEFT JOIN vendor_level ON user_info.username = vendor_level.vendor_id LEFT JOIN nearshore_and_offshore_locations ON user_info.username = nearshore_and_offshore_locations.vendor_id LEFT JOIN languages ON user_info.username = languages.vendor_id LEFT JOIN services ON user_info.username = services.vendor_id LEFT JOIN remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents ON user_info.username = remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents.vendor_id LEFT JOIN remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents_countries ON user_info.username = remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents_countries.vendor_id LEFT JOIN technology ON user_info.username = technology.vendor_id LEFT JOIN certifications_compliance ON user_info.username = certifications_compliance.vendor_id LEFT JOIN business_mix ON user_info.username = business_mix.vendor_id WHERE general_information.street_address LIKE '%%' AND (languages.languages = 'Amharic' OR languages.all_languages = 'all' ) GROUP BY user_info.username
```

How can i make my query to be not lost connection when query

Comment: You basically asked "how can my connection not drop when it gets dropped?"  Have you checked for error output in your PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`mysql_ping()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ping.html).

As Per [PHP Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ping.html) :

> Checks whether the connection to the server is working. If the
>   connection has gone down and auto-reconnect is enabled an attempt to
>   reconnect is made. If the connection is down and auto-reconnect is
>   disabled, mysql_ping() returns an error.

**Your Solution :**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_info LEFT JOiN general_information ON user_info.username = general_information.vendor_id LEFT JOIN company_information ON user_info.username = company_information.vendor_id LEFT JOIN usa_on_shore_site_locations ON user_info.username = usa_on_shore_site_locations.vendor_id LEFT JOIN core_competencies ON user_info.username = core_competencies.vendor_id LEFT JOIN industries_served ON user_info.username = industries_served.vendor_id LEFT JOIN vendor_level ON user_info.username = vendor_level.vendor_id LEFT JOIN nearshore_and_offshore_locations ON user_info.username = nearshore_and_offshore_locations.vendor_id LEFT JOIN languages ON user_info.username = languages.vendor_id LEFT JOIN services ON user_info.username = services.vendor_id LEFT JOIN remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents ON user_info.username = remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents.vendor_id LEFT JOIN remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents_countries ON user_info.username = remote_work_at_home_virtual_agents_countries.vendor_id LEFT JOIN technology ON user_info.username = technology.vendor_id LEFT JOIN certifications_compliance ON user_info.username = certifications_compliance.vendor_id LEFT JOIN business_mix ON user_info.username = business_mix.vendor_id WHERE general_information.street_address LIKE '%%' AND (languages.languages = 'Amharic' OR languages.all_languages = 'all' ) GROUP BY user_info.username"
while(!mysql_ping($connection)) {
    sleep(5);
}
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```